# Subclassing AssetsManager.AssetInputStream to read it with BitmapFactory.decodeStream

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, bitmapfactory

I want to override read() in AssetsManager.AssetInputStream to make some cross-read work (simple xor), but as it is inner class I can't just extend it, what should I do? And can I then create an instance of such class with existing instance of its outter class - Asset Manager?

Comment: "what should I do?" -- perhaps use composition rather than inheritance. `decodeStream()` works with any stream. So, create your own `InputStream` that wraps an `AssetInputStream`, where your `read()` delegates to the `AssetInputStream` `read()` and does the additional work.

Comment: Yes, but according to BitmapFactory sources it calls jni nativeDecodeAsset for assets, so I thought it is important to pass exactly  AssetsManager.AssetInputStream.

Comment: At least in the 9.0 CTS sources, *if* the stream is an `AssetInputStream`, it will use `nativeDecodeAsset()`. Otherwise, it will use `decodeStreamInternal()`. See [these lines](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-9.0_r3/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#L727-L732). They appear to be optimizing the asset scenario. In your case, it would fall to the `decodeStreamInternal()` case, which (hopefully) will work with your wrapped stream.